# How to I limit the net speed of my computer

Tags: networking, internet

We use broadband connection in my home. I use net to do study and see educational videos online. But my siblings use it to see movies and serials. Because of that the month allowance is getting finished quickly.

I use net in my laptop but I have the access to my desktop computer also.

I want to limit speed in my desktop computer.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most if not all ISP's cap bandwidth (basically, without being technical, it is how fast you are able to download something). Likewise, they also cap the amount of data you can download, known as a download quota. I assume you're more worried about the latter.

There could be a 1 GB file on the web. Whether it takes you hours to download it, or five minutes, it is still 1 GB, and it is that 1 GB of data that your provider is deducting from your monthly download quota.

So, limiting speed *may* help but only because it will annoy your siblings so much that they give up their particular habit of "movies and serial." Usually, bandwidth caps are handled by the ISP via the modem.

You'll simply need to explain to them that those things are simply off limits. Well, there's a solution for that too, but it's not so subtle. Block the website. There are several ways to do that. One could be adding the website to the HOSTS file (C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS if I recall correctly). They'll never find that. But, will they tolerate it?

Comment: I think the OP is living in an area where there indeed *are* monthly data caps (http://www.internet-compared.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If your broadband router supports [QoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) settings - the best way is to do it there.

Comment: This is the answer that O.P needed. As i also come from the same geography. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linux; Google around for traffic shaping/policing with `tc`.

Using Windows; Download NetBalancer and Google how to set it up.

Also, like others have suggested block those bandwidth hungry sites.

Comment: NetBalancer is not free